# Composite of two photos – how can I adjust the colours?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm a Photoshop newbie and I am having trouble achieving a specific effect for a composite. I started with these two photos:

[image: Background]

[image: Foreground]

I want to achieve this:

[image: Goal]

I was able to cut the girls out and kinda blend them with the background but I have no idea how to adjust the colours. This is what I have so far:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use the Camera RAW filter in Photoshop for such colour toning. It's good because all the controls are in the one place, and using the filter on a Smart Object is non-destructive.

Select both your layers, and go to *Filter > Convert for Smart Filters*. Then do *Filter > Camera RAW filter*.

As a starting point, use the following settings in the Basic tab (left) and Split Toning tab (right)

[image]

Here's the result - of course you can continue to tweak the settings a little until you get the desired result.

[image]